# How I can read XML by XPath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have method read XML from My XML file, I use `xpath` to get element from XML file but always get me object is null.
I want get all value element, but give me null.

that My method :

```
public ArrayList<Object> GetAnyEntity(String PathXPath) throws JAXBException {
        ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document dDoc = builder.parse("Projects//asdad//ProjectDataBase.xml");
            XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            NodeList nl = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate("//Project/Layer[@idLayer=2]", dDoc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                list.add(nl.item(i));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Project xmlns="http://www.example.org/ProjectDataBase" name="name1" >
    <Layer idLayer="2">
        <LayerName>a</LayerName>
        <Order>2</Order>
        <Visible>false</Visible>
    </Layer>
</Project>
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in a debugger?  Also, is why don't you include a standard XML header (indicating the page enconding, etc)?

Comment: I am update my code xml

Answer (score 0):

You're mising '' around the 2:

```
//Project/Layer[@idLayer='2']
```

Comment: but when I try print "for (Object number : list){System.out.println("layer= "+number);} result is "Number = [Layer:null]"